# I m trying to compute the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{ne^{n}}$ Thanks for the help!

Tags: sequences-and-series

I m trying to compute the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{ne^{n}}$

Thanks for the help!

Comment: We know $\ln (1-x)=-\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{x^n}{n}$. Now put $x=\dfrac{1}{e}$ (why can you do that?). So the answer is $1-\ln(e-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Can you sum the geometric series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{e^{an}}$?  Integrate both sides with respect to $a$, then set $a$ to $1$.

Comment: Actually, you want to integrate, because $n$ is in the denominator.

Comment: @RobertIsrael:  Right you are.  Thanks.

Comment: Would it not be better to leave this answer as a comment? Because the OP may get a wrong message that posting a question with no context (although downvoted) is answered anyway.